# How to display location in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When I visit http://maps.google.com on my iOS device, the current location is shown as in the image below.

[image: Google Maps on iOS]

I'm creating my own Map using the [Google Maps API v3](http://code.google.com/intl/da/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). How can I create this function?

I've tried their [sample using geolocation in the web browser](http://code.google.com/intl/da/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation.html) but it just displays an text box on my location. I would like it to be similar to the image above, where is it shown using the blue markers and a circle showing the accuracy. Is this default behavior if *Google Maps API v3* or should I design it myself using an icon, marker and circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the marker image by setting the icon property of the MarkerOptions object passed into the Marker constructor to show a custom image.
http://code.google.com/intl/da/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.8848, 14.7730),
   map: map,
   title: 'My workplace',
   clickable: false,
   icon: 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/factory.png'
});
```

Here is a site with some more information about using Google Maps API V3 http://www.svennerberg.com/tag/google-maps-api-3/

Comment: Yes, but my question was more about, if this could be done automatically by Google Maps or if I should implement it myself.

Comment: Google Maps API V3 provides only one marker out of the box, i.e., if you do not set the icon property, it would show a red colored balloon by default. If you need anything else, you need to set the icon property of the MarkerOptions object.